# How to create MySQL database in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I run the following Python script and receive the following error message:

> mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'check' at line 1")

When I changed the database from check to check1 it the script works and also I didn't have earlier defined "check" database.

```
import MySQLdb as db
db1 = db.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="vision@123")
cursor = db1.cursor()
sql = "CREATE DATABASE check;"
cursor.execute(sql)
db1.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

check is a reserved word.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

The also will fail:

```
Create database select;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check is a reserved word in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html and hence the error with "check" and not "check1".